# Navigation to ViewController via Push Segue opens screen then immediately closes it

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, navigation, segue

I have a `SearchViewController` that contains a `UITableView` that presents articles.

When pressing on an article, a navigation with segue command is called and the user is moved to the `ArticleViewController` screen so he can read the article.

For some reason, **after the article screen is opened** (you can see all the populated ui elements inside) **it immediately closes** and the user is back again in the search screen.

The navigation command is:

```
func actionButtonDidPress(inside article: Article) {
        selectedArticle = article
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Constants.Segues.SEARCH_TO_ARTICLE, sender: self)
    }
    
    override func prepare( for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any? ) {
        if let selectedArticle = selectedArticle {
            if segue.identifier == Constants.Segues.SEARCH_TO_ARTICLE {
                let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ArticleViewController
                destinationVC.currentArticle = selectedArticle
            }
        }
    }
```

I don't think it is something inside the `ArticleViewController` because when I do the same procedure from the `HomepageViewController` (table view with articles -> press on an article navigates to the article page) everything works with no issue.

Both times I use a `Show segue` and send the same elements into the ArticleViewController.

What can be causing this issue?

(When I switched to a Present Modally segue it solves the issue, but then I lose the TabBar that is supposed to be presented or lose other functionalities that are needed so I don't want this workaround)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a solution so eventually just switched all my segues in the app from "show" to "Present Modally" with "Presentation: Over Current Context" because this is the one that did work for the screen and was the closest in look to what I needed